# textarea and button are set to width 90% and 10% but are wrapping in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the input box and the send button box to be beside each other in the flex row, with the input taking 90% of the width. However, the send button is wrapping under the input and I'm not sure why.

```css
.chatFooter { /* footer */
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chatInput {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.chatSendBtn {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chatSendBtn:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatFooter">
  <textarea
     class="chatInput"
     placeholder="Enter message"
  ></textarea>

  <div class="chatSendBtn">
    Send
  </div>
</div>
```

edit: I added borders on my elements in the initial question so it was easier to see what was happening, but the original issue of the wrapping button exists without any buttons, I've removed the borders.

Comment: That s because of thé 1px border in each child div (set it to 0px and you will see they will align)

Comment: @Mehdi removing the borders doesn't fix the issue

Comment: You are right actualy Always used to place *{paddding:0; margin:0;box-sizing:border:box;} in css sheet so have not seen the issue

Comment: textarea have a default border so it there even if you remove it.

Comment: One of the main purpose of flex, is to avoid to use width and height. that is your first mistake and misunderstanding of how the flex layout works. To set the sizing behavior of the children , you have to use : flex (shorthands)  for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` .this avoids fixed width(90%/10%) and allows `gap`to be set and work with value set for box-sizing . `flex-wrap:wrap` is an option to use on the parent if this is what you want to see happening. `min-height`and `min-width`can be used in some cases , like building a repeating pattern.  flex-grow: 9\1 gives a 90%/10% ratio

Comment: @TemaniAfif hello, not sure it is the best duplicate. one of the nice thing about the flex layout is to get rid of setting fixed width or height and even more true when it is about % values ;) padding and borders are something, but gaps or margins can be around too .

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the way the standard [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) works. In the standard CSS box model, padding and borders are not included in the set dimensions. They are added to the set values, which increases the total size of the element. You have set borders around the elements which are being added to the set widths (i.e 90% and 10%) which make them bigger than the container and cause them to wrap.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
> element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
> has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
> to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen.

To solve it, add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the elements. When you add and set box-sizing to border-box, the width and height properties include the content, padding, and border. More- [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

```css
.chatFooter { /* footer */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.chatInput {
box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.chatSendBtn {
box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chatSendBtn:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatFooter">
  <textarea
     class="chatInput"
     placeholder="Enter message"
  ></textarea>

  <div class="chatSendBtn">
    Send
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this solution works, I actually only added borders to make it easier to see the issue. If I remove all borders (what I intend), how come the issue is there? (Again, the solution does work though, thanks!)

Comment: @chung It seems to be the problem of Stackoverflow and some other code runners. It works fine locally with Bracket. I have created a codesandbox and it works fine there too. Removing borders should work. Check it out- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/loving-moser-v74t3j

Comment: flex is supposed to do without width set , so it doesn't care about box-sizing, margins, paddings and gap values (use flex for the children , eventually min-height/width not width/heigth). the browser does the math itself. 90% and 10% is a ratio of 9 and 1 for flex grow (as an example for this case), or just gives a width to one or the other and the appropriate flex value to the other one. Beside , why keeping flex-wrap while the op wants a single row ?  ;) You may give a minor min-width assorted to a flex-grow:1 value. Just avoid the width or height to fully take advantage of a flex-layout ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus hmm you say when you use flex you shouldn't use widths and height, but I'm not sure how to achieve the layout I have now without them: https://codepen.io/MH-123/pen/wvZJPPZ How would I do that because if I replace height of `item-1` and `item-2` with flex ratios rather than heights, they just shrink to the wrapped heights of general `item` , which isn't big, so `item-3` just comes under `item-2`

Comment: use min-height instead, so the height remains *flexible* ;)

Comment: here is an example of the idea : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwOVoxo Once you set the flex properties on the child(ren) you can then add margin,padding,borders, gaps without the need to reset those flex properties. an extra or missing pixel will not break the flex layout you have set . height can be managed via min-height and max-height . Hope you understand better what i meant ;) . have fun

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width values and stop trying to control all the pixels. Since you're using flex, it is easiest to let the system do the fraction math for you. The sum of the flex units is calculated across the children of a parent that employs `display: flex;` In this case, 9+1=10, so give 9/10th of the space to the input and 1/10th of the space to the button as follows:

```
.chatInput {
  flex: 9;  /* instead of width: 90%; */
}
.chatSendBtn {
  flex: 1;  /* instead of width: 10%; */
}
```

In this system, you don't have to finesse the box model. You can freely apply margin padding and border and your flex units will naturally apply to the elements.

You might want to center them vertically in the parent container for aesthetics.

```
.chatFooter {
  align-items: center;  /* or maybe try top, depends how you like it */
}
```